# How to set MySQL session wait_timeout from the command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line-arguments

As you can see from the output below, I'm using the MySQL shell to change the session's `wait_timeout` variable to 30 seconds. It works.

However, Is there anyway to set this variable from the command line?

```
$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 48543
Server version: 5.6.39 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET session wait_timeout=30;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 30    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now() from dual;
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-01-23 17:16:52 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now() from dual;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does it:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 --init-command="SET SESSION wait_timeout=30"
```