# mysql - importing Tablespace: Lost connection during query

Tags: mysql

iam trying to recover innodb table which has 1.5M rows from ibd file ( 5.5 GB )

this is the exact steps i do:

1. getting create table query using mysqlfrm command
2. create the table
3. discard tablespace
4. moving the new tablespace to the db directory
5. import tablespace

and i'm getting this error :-

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
performance-schema=0
datadir=/home/mysql-serv
socket=/home/mysql-serv/mysql.sock
max_allowed_packet=26843545600
query_cache_size=8G
open_files_limit=10000
innodb_file_per_table=1
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,    NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
net_buffer_length=1000000
wait_timeout=28800
connect_timeout=28800
net_read_timeout=28800
net_write_timeout=28800
[client]
port=3306
socket=/home/mysql-serv/mysql.sock
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 26843545600
```

is there any way to import it ??

Comment: see if this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407513/how-to-set-mysql-session-wait-timeout-from-the-command-line

Comment: no it didn't help

Comment: i added my.cnf file content

Comment: with the session timeout  set to 0 the session can rin as long as it needs. Where do you enter your steps?